# Read CSV file up to line with unique marker

Tags: r, gsub, read.csv

I have many data sets that have extra information beyond a certain line. The files are all csv. I would be able to loop through them and read.csv with "skip" argument to clean the top of the data, but the length of the data frames are all different. The only commonality is the  "--------------- ---------------- ------ -----" line in the Total column that separates the meaningful data from summaries and extraneous info below it.

Here's how I'm reading in the data without skip = 14 (which is standard across everything).

```
before<-read.csv("Example.csv", header = FALSE,
             col.names = c("CountryID","Name","Type","Symbol","Code","Unit", 
"Total", "Measurement", "Value", "Percent", "CO2" ))
```

However, the ----- marker maybe a different row, but it's the first thing to hit. Here's the data before:

```
structure(list(CountryID = structure(c(26L, 19L, 21L, 23L, 21L, 
7L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 22L, 3L, 1L, 19L, 2L, 8L, 14L, 15L, 13L, 9L, 
12L, 18L, 17L, 8L, 13L, 15L, 10L, 8L, 8L, 11L, 16L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
20L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 25L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 24L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
"------------", "-------------", "---------------", "------------------", 
" ", "08.15.1997", "10000", "15000", "200", "2000", "2500", "3000", 
"45000", "5000", "7000", "8000", "8300", "Country", "Output", 
"Production", "Quantity", "Serial Output", "TOTAL SUM", "Unaccounted", 
"United Nations Data"), class = "factor"), Name = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 20L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 21L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 19L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
"--------------------", " ", "Bahrain", "Bangladesh", "Barbados", 
"Belarus", "Belgium", "Belize", "Benin", "Bhutan", "Bolivia", 
"Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Botswana", "Brazil", "Brunei", "Bulgaria", 
"Burkina Faso", "Chad", "Name", "The Bahamas"), class = "factor"), 
    Type = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "----", " ", "Code", "Type", 
    "Unit"), class = "factor"), Symbol = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 20L, 22L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 
    6L, 7L, 9L, 8L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
    19L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 21L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L), .Label = c("", "------------", " ", "BAHM", "BAHR", 
    "BANG", "BARB", "BELGM", "BELS", "BELZ", "BEN", "BHUT", "BOL", 
    "BOSHER", "BOTS", "BRAZ", "BRUN", "BULG", "BURKF", "Country", 
    "private", "Symbol"), class = "factor"), Code = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 19L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 12L, 
    15L, 11L, 17L, 4L, 13L, 14L, 9L, 18L, 10L, 5L, 16L, 3L, 7L, 
    8L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L), .Label = c("", "------------", "1504944270", "2287368539", 
    "2388991307", "2453202442", "2561470743", "3205402223", "3221488867", 
    "3230369605", "3247578406", "3712013344", "4307638090", "462793263", 
    "4835205752", "4854959101", "5842098895", "5932776587", "Code"
    ), class = "factor"), Unit = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 17L, 16L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 9L, 10L, 14L, 
    12L, 15L, 15L, 11L, 13L, 3L, 8L, 13L, 15L, 6L, 5L, 9L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
    "-------------", "100", "1109", "27", "35", "40", "45", "58", 
    "70", "74", "77", "79", "82", "95", "Output", "Per Unit"), class = "factor"), 
    Total = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 25L, 
    24L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 18L, 5L, 17L, 8L, 23L, 20L, 6L, 9L, 
    7L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 19L, 15L, 14L, 10L, 3L, 16L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    16L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 21L, 1L, 3L, 22L, 4L), .Label = c("", "---------------", 
    "---------------            ----------------  ------  -----", 
    "===============            ================  ======  =====", 
    "126912", "147431", "170553", "175973", "203728", "230761", 
    "293789", "304471", "376281", "386526", "399160", "4417002", 
    "476025", "478030", "502999", "51012", "5610654", "56406056", 
    "93351", "Output", "Total"), class = "factor"), Measurement = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 12L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
    9L, 3L, 4L, 10L, 9L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 10L, 7L, 9L, 4L, 8L, 10L, 
    9L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 11L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L), .Label = c("", "--------", "20", "23", "24", "26", "27", 
    "28", "29", "30", "420", "Measurement"), class = "factor"), 
    Value = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 22L, 
    23L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 19L, 11L, 8L, 3L, 18L, 13L, 6L, 
    4L, 9L, 14L, 17L, 7L, 10L, 12L, 15L, 1L, 16L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    16L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 20L, 1L, 1L, 21L, 1L), .Label = c("", "----------------", 
    "15150240", "15891735", "16083459", "16959919", "20350968", 
    "20909501", "21770264", "25121096", "27726279", "30024743", 
    "34069742", "34841369", "38498281", "468004111", "49524999", 
    "50512814", "50568702", "540650", "64506", "Country", "Value"
    ), class = "factor"), Percent = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 23L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 11L, 12L, 8L, 3L, 
    17L, 16L, 5L, 10L, 20L, 9L, 6L, 7L, 4L, 15L, 14L, 22L, 1L, 
    13L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 21L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 19L, 1L, 1L, 18L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
    "------", "102", "104", "106", "112", "126", "129", "142", 
    "15", "160", "177", "1775", "180", "191", "24", "25", "5640645", 
    "650163", "87", "887.5", "95", "Production Percent"), class = "factor"), 
    CO2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 15L, 14L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 9L, 4L, 9L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 7L, 4L, 9L, 4L, 
    11L, 4L, 12L, 10L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    3L, 1L, 1L, 13L, 1L), .Label = c("", "-----", "?", "0", "0.2", 
    "0.6", "1", "19.4", "2", "2.2", "4", "5", "564065", "CO2", 
    "Cur."), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-44L))
```

And here's how I'm hoping it could look:

```
structure(list(CountryID = c(10000L, 45000L, 5000L, 3000L, 15000L, 
2500L, 8300L, 8000L, 10000L, 3000L, 5000L, 200L, 10000L, 10000L, 
2000L, 7000L), Name = structure(c(16L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L), .Label = c("Bahrain", 
"Bangladesh", "Barbados", "Belarus", "Belgium", "Belize", "Benin", 
"Bhutan", "Bolivia", "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Botswana", "Brazil", 
"Brunei", "Bulgaria", "Burkina Faso", "The Bahamas"), class = "factor"), 
    Type = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Unit", class = "factor"), 
    Symbol = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
    10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L), .Label = c("BAHM", "BAHR", 
    "BANG", "BARB", "BELGM", "BELS", "BELZ", "BEN", "BHUT", "BOL", 
    "BOSHER", "BOTS", "BRAZ", "BRUN", "BULG", "BURKF"), class = "factor"), 
    Code = c(3712013344, 4835205752, 3247578406, 5842098895, 
    2287368539, 4307638090, 462793263, 3221488867, 5932776587, 
    3230369605, 2388991307, 4854959101, 1504944270, 2561470743, 
    3205402223, 2453202442), Unit = c(40L, 58L, 70L, 82L, 77L, 
    95L, 95L, 74L, 79L, 100L, 45L, 79L, 95L, 35L, 27L, 58L), 
    Total = c(478030L, 126912L, 476025L, 175973L, 93351L, 51012L, 
    147431L, 203728L, 170553L, 293789L, 304471L, 376281L, 502999L, 
    399160L, 386526L, 230761L), Measurement = c(20L, 29L, 20L, 
    23L, 30L, 29L, 26L, 23L, 24L, 30L, 27L, 29L, 23L, 28L, 30L, 
    29L), Value = c(16083459L, 50568702L, 27726279L, 20909501L, 
    15150240L, 50512814L, 34069742L, 16959919L, 15891735L, 21770264L, 
    34841369L, 49524999L, 20350968L, 25121096L, 30024743L, 38498281L
    ), Percent = c(160L, 177L, 129L, 102L, 25L, 24L, 106L, 15L, 
    87L, 142L, 112L, 126L, 104L, 191L, 180L, 95L), CO2 = c(2, 
    0, 2, 1, 0, 0.2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 4, 0, 5, 2.2, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-16L))
```

Can this be integrated into the read.csv argument, or is it easier to clean the bottom of it some other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three thoughts:

1. Use `readLines` (as @user2554330 suggested), find/remove the specific row, filter it, then parse the text vector with `read.csv`, the least of the three.
2. `before[seq_len(min(head(which(!grepl("^[^- ]+$", before$Total)),1)-1L,nrow(before))),]`; a bit complicated, granted, but it does what you need (assuming that you've already filtered the first 14 rows with `skip=`.
3. Use an external script such as `sed -e '1,14d;/^[ -]\+$/{g;q;}` in a `pipe(...)`-type thing.

Comment: Genius. I completely forgot that after skipping the lines that the first - character would be where I want the df to cutoff. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Read it twice.  The first time, use `readLines("Example.csv")`, and look through the lines for the marker of the end of data.  Say it's on line n.  Then in the second read, use

```
read.csv("Example.csv", header = FALSE,
         col.names = c("CountryID","Name","Type","Symbol","Code","Unit", 
         "Total", "Measurement", "Value", "Percent", "CO2" ), nrows = n - 1)
```

(or maybe `nrows` will need to be a different value, if you're skipping some).